# How to fix Bash script thrown off by ssh option?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have the following Bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set port [lindex $argv 0]
set cmd_target [lindex $argv 1]
set login [lindex $argv 2]@[lindex $argv 3]
set username [lindex $argv 2]
set hostname [lindex $argv 3]
set password [lindex $argv 4]

spawn ssh -X -p $port $login $cmd_target
expect {
    {Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/\[fingerprint\])?}
    {
        exp_send "yes\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    {password:} {send "$password\r"}    
}
expect eof
```

It works find if I use it as follows:

```
$ port_0=22
$ username_0=somename
$ hostname_0=192.168.70.92
$ password_0=...
$ cmd_target="pwd"
$ ./my_script $port_0 $cmd_target $username_0 $hostname_0 $password_0
```

The output is:

```
spawn ssh -X -p 22 somename@192.168.70.92 pwd
somename@192.168.70.92's password: 
/home/somename
```

However if I use `cmd_target="ls -la"`, the script is thrown off:

```
spawn ssh -X -p 22 -la@somename ls
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ls: Temporary failure in name resolution
expect: spawn id exp4 not open
    while executing
"expect eof"
```

Why is this happening?  How can I get it to work as intended?  Frustratingly, this works just fine:

```
ssh $username_0@$hostname_0 ls -la
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a Bash script, it's a Tcl/Expect script that's only being invoked from Bash.

> Why is this happening?

Within Bash, all `$` expansions are subject to word-splitting unless quoted, therefore your script receives `[lindex $argv 1] => "ls"` and `[lindex $argv 2] => "-la"`.

> How can I get it to work as intended?

When running the script from Bash, make sure to use double-quotes around the variable, like you would when specifying a literal argument with spaces:

```sh
./my_script $port_0 "$cmd_target" $username_0 $hostname_0 "$password_0"
```

Unquoted expansions are also subject to wildcard (glob) processing, so you will want to put quotes around `"$password"` as well (just in case it ever contains a `*` or such) – and in general around any expansion, really.

This does not apply to your Expect script; `spawn ssh ... $cmd_target` is fine in Tcl.

Comment: Thank you for the enlightenment.  It works now!